# Equivalent definitions of Yangian for $\mathfrak{sl}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I know several definitions of Yangian $Y(\mathfrak{sl}_n)$:

1. Consider the Yangian $Y(\mathfrak{gl}_n)$, i.e.
   $$R(u - v) T_1(u) T_2(v) = T_2(v) T_1(u) R(u-v)$$
   Consider homomorphism $\mu_f : T(u) \mapsto f(u)T(u)$. Define Yangian
   as invariants of these transformations, i.e.
   $$Y(\mathfrak{sl}_n) := \{ y\in Y(\mathfrak{gl}_n): \mu_f(y) = y\; \forall f\}$$
   This definition is taken from [Yangians and Classical Lie Algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9409025).
2. Take an orthonormal basis $z_\mu \in \mathfrak{sl}_n$ w.r.t. standard Killing form.
   Define $Y_{\lambda}(\mathfrak{sl}_n)$ as algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ generated by elements $z, J(z);\ z \in \mathfrak{sl}_n$ satisfying the following relations:
   \begin{align}
   & J(az_1 + bz_2) = aJ(z_1) + bJ(z_2)\\
   & [z_1, J(z_2)] = J([z_1, z_2])\\
   & [J(z_1), J([z_2, z_3])] + [J(z_3), J([z_1, z_2])] + [J(z_2), J([z_3, z_1])]
   = \lambda^2\sum_{\sigma, \mu, \nu} ([z_1, z_\sigma], [[z_2, z_\mu], [z_3, z_\nu]])\{z_\sigma, z_\mu, z_\nu\} 
   \end{align}
   where
   $$\{z_1, z_2, z_3\} := \frac{1}{24}\sum_{\pi \in S_3} z_{\pi(1)} z_{\pi(2)} z_{\pi(3)}$$
   This definition is taken from [Affine Yangians and deformed double current algebras
   in type A](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Enguay/NGuayAffYangDDCA.pdf)

Each of the references contains a handful of other definitions, and equivalences are proved. However, I could not find a reference, which shows any connection of the above two definitions. I am looking for a reference which explains the connection between the above two definitions, or contains some other equivalent definitions and proves them, so that I can better understand the true meaning of the definition.